# When I call a stored procedure from C# it throws an exception

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetDatabaseBackup
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @MyFileName varchar(1000)

    SELECT 
       @MyFileName= 'D:\DATABASE-BACKUP\genxMultiERPLive -' +      
              REPLACE(convert(nvarchar(20),GetDate(),120),':','-') + '.bak'

    BACKUP DATABASE genxMultiERPLive 
    TO DISK = @MyFileName   
END
GO
```

This is my stored procedure. When I execute this stored procedure, it works fine. When I call with the object of database in my C# code, it throws an exception.

```
public bool DataBaseBackup()
{
    int obj = _dbContext.GetDatabaseBackup();

    if (obj != 0)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return  false;
}
```

`_dbContext` is object of my data base.

Exception is :

> Cannot perform a backup or restore operation within a transaction.
>   BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: Does `_dbContext.GetDatBaseBackup()` use transaction in it's body?

Comment: I think EF uses transactions out of the box.
So, if that's true you need to work out how to call this procedure in particular outside of a transaaction......as that is what the error is moaning about.

Looks like Haitham Shaddad has posted a solution for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the line that call the stored procedure from

`int obj= _dbContext.GetDatBaseBackup();`
To

`_dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction,"GetDatBaseBackup");`